# Maxwell Render 4.x – Error writing MXI file after rendering

Tags: qt, io, windows-7-x64, 3d-rendering

A customer is using maxwell render (manager, monitor and node) on a windows 7 64bit machine. 
When the scene has finished rendering the following error messages comes up:

```
-node
QObject::connect: No such signal QApplication::messageReceived( const QString& )

QIODevice::seek (QTcpSocket): Cannot call seek on a sequential device
QIODevice::seek (QTcpSocket): Cannot call seek on a sequential device
QIODevice::seek (QTcpSocket): Cannot call seek on a sequential device
QIODevice::seek (QTcpSocket): Cannot call seek on a sequential device
QIODevice::seek (QTcpSocket): Cannot call seek on a sequential device
QIODevice::seek (QTcpSocket): Cannot call seek on a sequential device
```

I have 3 questions:

1. Am I correct, that this message means that the node is not able to
   write to the hard disk?
2. Does »QTcpSocket« indicate that there may be a problem with the network configuration and/or the firewall settings of the machine itself?
3. Is there a tool to log/monitor the network read/write attemps in order to find the network path the node can't access?

Comment: You'd be correct at saying that the application has bugs. That's all.

Comment: 1 - it is not evident from the info you provided, nor does it suggest it in any way, 2 - it indicates the code is calling seek on a device that doesn't support seeking, 3 - there are various network sniffers / packet analyzers out there

Answer (score 0):

The message is harmless and does not affect the network well functioning. It is shown by Qt, the platform upon the interface is built.